# How to get default locking hint of a table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, locking

Is there is any way to get default **locking hint** using a query. I want to know whether the locking use by my transaction is `tablock | rowlock | nolock` etc.

Answer (score 1):

You can run you query in a transaction and run sp_lock @@spid after running the query, you will know all the locks held.